# How filter woocommerce products by min and max values of attribute?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The products have the attribute Tempo. This is a text field in which to enter the number.

How to sort products by the minimum and maximum attribute value? 
using such url `?filtering=1&filter_min-tempo=100&filter_max-tempo=150`

Is it possible to create an attribute of type integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All attributes are stored as text, but you can cast them to the type you need.

Look at this code:

```
function isequal($v1,$v2) {
    return intval($v1) == intval($v2);
}

function filter_loop_shop_post_in( $array ) { 
    if ( !array_key_exists('min_tempo',$_GET) && !array_key_exists('max_tempo',$_GET) ) return $array;
    global $wpdb;

    $min = isset( $_GET['min_tempo'] ) ? floatval( $_GET['min_tempo'] ) : 0;
    $max = isset( $_GET['max_tempo'] ) ? floatval( $_GET['max_tempo'] ) : 9999999999;

    $query = "
    SELECT DISTINCT
        tr.object_id
    FROM
        {$wpdb->term_relationships} AS tr
    LEFT JOIN
        {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} AS tt
    ON
        tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
    LEFT JOIN
        {$wpdb->terms} AS t
    ON
        tt.term_id = t.term_id
    WHERE
        tt.`taxonomy` = 'pa_tempo' AND CAST(t.name AS DECIMAL(10, 1)) BETWEEN $min AND $max";

    $raw_results = $wpdb->get_results( $query );
    if (!sizeof($raw_results)) return $array;
    $results = array();
    foreach ($raw_results as $res) {
        $results[] = intval($res->object_id);
    }
    if (!sizeof($array)) return $results;
    return array_uintersect($results, $array, 'isequal');
}; 
add_filter( 'loop_shop_post_in', 'filter_loop_shop_post_in', 10, 1 );
```

It works for me in WooCommerce 2.6.14.